# WPF. Pattern animation class

Tags: wpf, loops, animation, design-patterns, usability

[I created a `DrawingLine` animation class to draw patterns.

The constructor starts the process of creating and animating lines:

```
internal DrawingLine(double x, double y, int _thickness, Brush _brush, Canvas _canvas)
```

At the end of the animation, this method generates a new line:

```
void CreateNewLine(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Line newLine = new Line();

            switch (lines.Count % 2 == 0)
            {
                case true:
                    {
                        if (lines.Count < 18)
                        {
                                    newLine.X1 = 0;
                                    newLine.Y1 = 180 - offset;
                                    newLine.X2 = 0;
                                    newLine.Y2 = 180 - offset;
                        }

                        //   ...   <-- Here is the math determines the positions of the points of the line

        }
```

The method produces animation:

```
void AnimateXY()
        {
            DoubleAnimation lineXAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            lineXAnimation.From = CurrentLine.X1;
            lineXAnimation.To = to_X;
            lineXAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);

            DoubleAnimation lineYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            lineYAnimation.From = CurrentLine.Y1;
            lineYAnimation.To = to_Y;
            lineYAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
            lineYAnimation.Completed += CreateNewLine;

            CurrentLine.BeginAnimation(Line.X2Property, lineXAnimation);
            CurrentLine.BeginAnimation(Line.Y2Property, lineYAnimation);
        }
```

Question: What is the best way to loop this animation, so that there are no memory leaks? I would also like to hear general recommendations for improving the structure of such classes. Picture of the pattern is attached.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AzS0.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. If the class is full of animation, then it supports a recursive call (recursive creation). A recursive call makes the animation endless.